# Magento 1.9 change package folder and theme name

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

could someone explain to me how can I change the package folder and the theme name of a Magento 1.9.3 theme that I downloaded and installed?

Answer (score 0):

For Changing Theme name You must Have to Override All Previous **Theme Dependency name, Resources Name** ....

you Can Do One Thing Find **ThemePackage** Name And Override it With Your And After that Set your **ThemePackage** for Resources That do Conflicts..